# `refold :: Functor s => (a -> s a, a) -> (s b -> b) -> b` as a morphism between universal types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold, category-theory, recursion-schemes

Various recursion scheme boil down to specific instantiation of `refold`

```hs
refold :: Functor s => (s b -> b) -> (a -> s a) -> a -> b
refold f g = go where go a = f (fmap go (g a))
```

What is the meaningful interpretation of `refold` ?

The data type `data Nu f = forall a. Nu (a -> f a) a` and `newtype Mu f = Mu {unMu :: forall b. (f b -> b) -> b}` can be seen as the colimit and limit of the forget functor from coalgebras and algebras, and `refold` is a morphism between those, but does it shed light on `refold` ?

```hs
refold' :: forall s. Functor s => Nu s -> Mu s
refold' (Nu g (a :: a)) = Mu mu where

  mu :: forall b. (s b -> b) -> b
  mu f = go a where

    go :: a -> b
    go a = f (fmap go (g a))
```

Comment: Non-termination might play a tricky role here. Consider `f a = Either () a`. Now `Mu f` is the type of (finite) natural numbers, while `Nu f` also adds an "infinity" value to naturals. Yet, we have isos `isoNu :: f (Nu f) -> Nu f` and `isoMu :: Mu f -> f (Mu f)`, which give us `refold isoNu isoMu :: Nu f -> Mu f`. I believe this has to diverge on the "infinity" value.

Comment: @chi another argument : let's take s = identity. the type suggest it has to diverge

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends what you mean by "meaningful interpretation".

If `s` is a base functor for a recursive data type and a corecursive codata type, like the following functor `s ~ ListF e` for the recursive list data type `[e]` (which, in Haskell, is also a corecursive stream codata type):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data ListF e b = Nil | Cons e b deriving (Show, Functor)
```

then an `s`-coalgebra of type `a -> s a` together with a starting seed `a` can generate a value of codata type `[e]` by unfolding from that seed, while an `s`-algebra of type `s b -> b` can consume a value of data type `[e]` by folding into a value of type `b`.  The `refold` function just combines the operation of unfolding from `a` and folding into `b`, without actually creating an intermediate codata/data type.

For example, you can generate the (finite) codata stream `[10,9..1]` by unfolding from an `Integer` seed using the starting value / coalgebra pair `(a,g)` as follows:

```
a :: Integer
a = 10

g :: Integer -> (ListF Integer) Integer
g 0 = Nil
g n = Cons n (n-1)
```

and fold a list to calculate its `Int` length using the algebra:

```
f :: (ListF Integer) Int -> Int
f Nil = 0
f (Cons _ b) = 1 + b
```

The `refold` function just combines these operations:

```
main = print $ refold f g a
```

In this particular case, it calculates the length `10` of the stream/list `[1..10]` without actually creating any intermediate stream/list.

I guess the intuition is that if an operation can be imagined as an F-recursion applied to an F-corecursion for the same functor F, then it's a `refold`.  Or, maybe more practically, if an algorithm has an internal recursive structure that matches the functor F, it can be expressed as a `refold`.  The [documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.24/recursion-schemes-5.2.2.2/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:refold) for `refold` in `recursion-schemes` gives the example of quicksort having a recursive structure that matches a binary tree, though you've presumably already seen that example.

*Note: What follows is wrong or at best imprecise, but I'll try to think a little more about it.*

<s>In practice, `refold` isn't only used as a morphism between universal data types, but if you have a *final* s-coalgebra for a codata type `C` associated with the functor `s`:</s>

```
eatC :: C -> ListF Integer C
```

and an *initial* s-algebra for a data type `D` also associated with the functor `s`:

```
makeD :: ListF Integer D -> D
```

then `refold makeD eatC` should be a natural morphism from codata type `C` to data type `D`.  That is, it should be the unique morphism satsifying:

```
fmap h . refold makeD eatC = refold makeD eatC . fmap h
```

I'm not sure that aspect is tremendously interesting...

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks (which I imagine to be valid - don't hesitate to correct - I am not an expert on semantic) :

- non termination allow to write anything, as @chi suggested.
  take `s` the identity functor and `refold` reads `refold :: (b -> b) -> (a -> a) -> a -> b` which certainly looks like a paradox. So for any haskell type to be read "logically", we might need hidden, side conditions.

We don't even need recursion to encounter paradox / non termination

```hs
-- N. P. Mendler. Recursive types and type constraints in second-order lambda calculus. In LICS, pages 30–36. IEEE Computer Society, 1987
data T a = C (T a -> ())

p :: T a -> (T a ->() )
p (C f) = f

w :: T a -> ()
w x = (p x) x
```

- *initial algebra*, like *monads*, and other concepts, happens on two level, one in the semantic of a language, and another explicitly in the program that we write. For instance the *semantic* of `data ListInt = [] | Int * ListInt` is an initial algebra. and, in haskell, also, semantically, a final coalgebra. This is "Mu = Nu" that you might hear,and this equation, which is paradoxical, happens is in the semantic of haskell. `Mu` here has nothing to do with `data Mu f = ..`. The same happen when we write `type ListInt = Fix ListIntF` where `data Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))` we are *emulating* that semantic in our program, but this itself is subject to the semantic of Haskell (and indeed, this (initial algebra) is the same as the semantic `Mu` and `Nu` and equal to both because haskell equates them). In a way by writing `data Mu f = ...` and `data Nu f = ..` we are  "stealing" (and obliged to do so) part of haskell semantic, as well as mixing it with our own (properly expressing the universal co-cone `Nu f` and the universal cone `Mu f`), attempting at providing an embedding for recursion (just like we do with HOAS where we steal bindings from Haskell). But we can't get away with no paradox, as we are **obliged** to steal that "Mu = Nu".

  This leads to very useful and yet very "illogical" function like `refold`
- By writing `fold : Functor s => (f a -> a) -> Fix s -> a` we are pretending the initial algebra of `f` always exists, which might translate to non-termination

Categorically we can view `refold` in two different ways. It's a bit of a mouthful but here we go :

- `refold` can be seen as a proper function `refold :: Functor s => (s b -> b) -> (a -> s a) -> a -> b` to be detailed later
- `refold'` can be seen as the **carrier** `refold' :: forall s. Functor s => Nu s -> Mu s` of an algebra in `Twisted(Hask)`, whose objects are morphisms in `Hask`. So `refold'` is an object, not a morphism, of this category. Now every functor `s` on a category `C` (here `Hask`) induces a functor `s'` on `Twisted(C)` by applying to arrows. In the end the morphism in `Twisted`

  ```
               `s' refold' -(out,in)-> refold'`
  ```

  is the initial `s'` algebra, where `out` is the "final" coalgebra `Nu s -> s (Nu s)`  and `in` is the "initial" algebra  `Mu s -> s (Mu s)`

Now the action of the *function* `refold` is, given a coalgebra and an algebra (here in `Hask` but could be elsewhere), to return the unique morphism from the carrier of the coalgebra, followed by `refold'`, followed by the unique morphism from the initial algebra. This is a proper *function* that comes from selecting the components of the universal (co)cone at the given components.

This explains why when we feed the final coalgebra `out` and the initial algebra `in` to `refold`, we get back `refold'` itself. the unique morphism to pre and post compose `refold'` with are the identities.

It's a bit hard to see what's what because we work in `Hask` where everything is a function. Some morphisms are really about the category we work in (could be other things than `Hask`) and some morphism really are functions would be even if we chose another category.

Because of non termination the solution to knowing what *really* is `refold` has to being truthful to the semantic of haskell, and use complete partial order (or to restrict `s` in some way).

So I imagine the real meaning of `refold` can be deduced from the real meaning of `refold'` which is just a initial algebra, with all the standard caveat coming from haskell semantic threaded.

Comment: It seems to me that a function of type `forall s. Functor s => Nu s -> Mu s` cannot possibly be always terminating. Because `Nu s` could be infinite, it cannot be correctly mapped into `Mu s` and so `refold` must be a partial function.